# How to add vertical space between two figures in tikzpicture environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I would like to add a vertical space between two figures in tikzpicture environment. I use this option to have y axis aligned. So, how can I add a vertical space between figures?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{semilogyaxis}[
            name=min_AQ_3DFT,
            xmin=0,  xmax=8, ymin=1e-12, ymax=2,
            xtick={0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
            ytick={1e-11, 1e-10, 1e-9, 1e-8, 1e-7, 1e-6, 1e-5, 1e-4, 1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1, 1},
            xmajorgrids=true, ymajorgrids=true, yminorticks=true,
            xlabel=$\theta_m$, ylabel=$\left|e\left(\frac{A_{m,1}}{A_{m,2}}\right)\right|_{max}$,
            legend style={draw=none, legend pos=south west,font=\tiny} ]
            \addplot {x^2/1e6};
            %\addplot [color=Paired12qual2] table [x index=0, y index=1] {min_AQ_3DFT_err_L_MSD_THD10p.dat};
            %\addplot [color=Paired12qual4] table [x index=0, y index=1] {min_AQ_3DFT_err_L_MSL_THD10p.dat};
            \legend{min(3DFT)@MSD, min(3DFT)@MSL}
        \end{semilogyaxis}
%
        \begin{axis}[
            at=(min_AQ_3DFT.below south), anchor=above north,
            xmin=0,  xmax=8, ymin=0, ymax=9,
            y=0.5cm/2,
            xtick={0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
            ytick={2, 4, 6, 8},
            xmajorgrids=true, ymajorgrids=true, yminorticks=true,
            xlabel=$\theta_m$, ylabel=$L$,
            legend style={draw=none, legend pos=south east,font=\tiny} ]
            \addplot {x};
            \legend{min(3DFT)@MSD, min(3DFT)@MSL}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add add a `yshift` in the options of second axis environment. I.e.,

```
\begin{axis}[
    at=(min_AQ_3DFT.below south), anchor=above north,
    xmin=0,  xmax=8, ymin=0, ymax=9,
    y=0.5cm/2,
    xtick={0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
    ytick={2, 4, 6, 8},
    xmajorgrids=true, ymajorgrids=true, yminorticks=true,
    xlabel=$\theta_m$, ylabel=$L$,
    legend style={draw=none, legend pos=south east,font=\tiny},
    yshift=-1cm ] % <-- pay attention to me!
    \addplot {x};
    \legend{min(3DFT)@MSD, min(3DFT)@MSL}
\end{axis}
```